use a hook inside a function
I'm a beginner in react and JS. I want to refactor and clean up my endless files a little and seperating in files for different tasks.
So I created a lib folder and created a file called calculatePercentage.js and I want to use a useContext hook there. How is this possible to achieve? Do I need to create a component?
this is not possible:
import { addDays, differenceInCalendarDays } from "date-fns";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { TimelineSettingsContext } from "../TimelineSettingsProvider";

// Function to calculate the percentage difference between two dates
export function calculatePercentage(startDate, endDate) {
  const { timelineStart, timelineLength, timelineScale } = useContext(
    TimelineSettingsContext
  );
  //wenn startDate vor dem TimelineStart liegt, dass muss der Balken verkürzt werden und startet bei timelineStart
  startDate =
    differenceInCalendarDays(timelineStart, startDate) < 0
      ? startDate
      : timelineStart;
  const startPosition =
    (differenceInCalendarDays(startDate, timelineStart) / timelineLength) *
    timelineScale;
  const width =
    (differenceInCalendarDays(addDays(endDate, 1), startDate) /
      timelineLength) *
    timelineScale;
  return { startPosition, width };
}


Now after solving that error with comment below. Getting another error from the calling component:
import { differenceInCalendarDays } from "date-fns";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import BackgroundColumns from "./BackgroundColumns";
import BookingBar from "./BookingBar";
import { TimelineSettingsContext } from "../../TimelineSettingsProvider";
import { useCalculatePercentage } from "../../lib/calculatePercentage";

const Timeline = () => {
  const { groupedBookings, dates, setSelectedBooking } = useContext(
    TimelineSettingsContext
  );

  function handleBookingSelected(booking) {
    setSelectedBooking(booking.LfdNr);
  }

  return (
    <div className="whitespace-nowrap relative">
      <div className="absolute flex w-full h-full">
        {dates?.map((date, index) => {
          const { width } = useCalculatePercentage(new Date(), new Date());
          return (
            <BackgroundColumns
              key={index}
              date={date}
              width={width}
            ></BackgroundColumns>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="relative flex flex-col z-20 pt-8">
        {groupedBookings.map((category, index) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <div
                className="h-8"
                key={`${index}`} // Verwenden Sie eine eindeutige Kombination aus index und idx für den key
              />
              {category.bookings.map((booking, idx) => {
                const { startPosition, width } = useCalculatePercentage(
                  new Date(booking.Beginn_Datum),
                  new Date(booking.Ende_Datum)
                );
                const bookingLength =
                  differenceInCalendarDays(
                    booking.Ende_Datum,
                    booking.Beginn_Datum
                  ) + 1;

                return (
                  <BookingBar
                    callbackBarClicked={() => handleBookingSelected(booking)}
                    key={booking.LfdNr} // Verwenden Sie eine eindeutige Kombination aus index und idx für den key
                    startPosition={startPosition}
                    width={width}
                    index={index}
                    label={`${bookingLength} ${
                      bookingLength > 1 ? "days" : "day"
                    }`}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timeline;



Yeah, as you noticed, you can't use hooks in functions. React hooks can only be called inside a function component or from another custom hook. So when dealing with non JSX returns you would make another hook from within which you can call the hooks you need to use. So in this case you would likely write something like
export function useCalculatePercentage(startDate, endDate) {
  const { timelineStart, timelineLength, timelineScale } = useContext(
    TimelineSettingsContext,
  );
  // ...
  return { startPosition, width };
}

And then you have a new hook that you can use to get the percentage value as you need. And that again needs to be called at the top level in a function component or another hook.
In your case, where you use useCalculatePercentage it will not work as intended or it will give warnings. You should call the hook in the top level of the function, so no loops, no callbacks, just somewhere here
const Timeline = () => {
  const { groupedBookings, dates, setSelectedBooking } = useContext(
    TimelineSettingsContext
  );
  //<--- call hook


  function handleBookingSelected(booking) {
    setSelectedBooking(booking.LfdNr);
  }

  //<--- or  here

I think its something to do with how react keeps track of the hooks, so essentially one of the main things is that the number of calls to the hook must be consistent across renderers, and even sometimes calling the hooks in maps etc like in your example can yield a consistent number of hook calls over the time period it is required but it's no guarantee so react warns against it. So its kind of going against the design of react so not worth the headache.
In your situation, for the first call, it's easy to move the call to the hook outside of any callbacks since the arguments are just current date so it's the same for all elements that would be iterated over if in the map function. But the second callback is more complicated. But if you want to use a hook here, you could return a function from the hook. So basically the hook itself can get all the variables required from react, so other hooks, including context values like in your case and return a function that takes regular variables and then returns the value. So could look something like
export function useCalculatePercentageWithContext() {
  const { timelineStart, timelineLength, timelineScale } = useContext(
    TimelineSettingsContext,
  );

  const calculatePercentage = (start, end) => {
    //...
    return { startPosition, width };
  };
  return calculatePercentage;
}

and since calculate percentage is just a normal function you can call that wherever you want, so would use like
const Timeline = () => {
  const { groupedBookings, dates, setSelectedBooking } = useContext(
    TimelineSettingsContext
  );
  const calculatePercentage = useCalculatePercentageWithContext();

  //....

{category.bookings.map((booking, idx) => {
     const { startPosition, width } = calculatePercentage(
        new Date(booking.Beginn_Datum),new Date(booking.Ende_Datum))...}

And this will work fine, but in my opinion it can quickly becomes annoying to have all these hooks, and every time you want to add some functionality you have to make another hook that uses some hooks etc..
If I were refactoring this I would call the context hook in the component and have a normal function somewhere and simply pass it the arguments, including those from context. Something like
export function calculatePercentage({
  timelineStart,
  timelineLength,
  timelineScale,
  startDate,
  endDate,
}) {
  ///... logic
  return { startPosition, width };
}


then in timeline
const { timelineStart, timelineLength, timelineScale } = useContext(
  TimelineSettingsContext,
);

and
{category.bookings.map((booking, idx) => {
  const { startPosition, width } = calculatePercentage({
     start:new Date(booking.Beginn_Datum),
     end:new Date(booking.Ende_Datum),
     timelineStart,
     timelineLength,
     timelineScale,
  });

and I think will be a lot simpler like this.

this error is gone, but now getting: Error: React Hook "useCalculatePercentage" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function. I will add the calling component in my post

in react its important you don't call hooks outside of the top level body of the function component or hook even. So if you call it in map it wont work nicely. In theory I guess it is possible if the array is fixed in length over a certain lifecycle but they're not designed to be used like that, if you just look up rules of hooks react you can see a good explanation. But if you add the rest of the code where you call the hook can look into that.

oh this looms interesting but with my current knowledge I'm afraid I won't get it if I'm looking at the code in a few weeks. So I think easiest solution is to pass the missing properties into the function instead of using the useContext hook

ahah yeah it is interesting but also a pain, I would honestly suggest using custom hooks only for situations where this is extremely useful. I added in the answer that I think a much easier, and in my opinion, a better solution is to just get the context variables in the component and pass them to the function.

I'll add an example

haha alright, thats where I came from. But makes sense. I'll get back to it.
